# MySQL JOIN Posts - Tags is taking too long

Tags: mysql, join, tags, posts

I'm facing some performance issues on MySQL JOIN statement. It's basically a posts-tags relationship with many rows: about 100000 posts and 20000 tags.
Unfortunately the query takes too long so that's what I'm asking for your help.
In a very basic query I need to get specific posts columns plus concatenated tags for each post. In fact the real query is more complex but I could start from here.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS null as rows,
  posts.id,
  posts.title
  GROUP_CONCAT(tags.desc SEPARATOR ", ") as ptags
FROM posts
JOIN posts_tags ON posts_tags.id_post = posts.id
JOIN tags ON tags.id = posts_tags.id_tag
GROUP BY posts.id
ORDER BY posts.id DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```

These are my keys definition

```
--- POSTS Table ----
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

--- POSTS_TAGS Table ----
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_post` (`id_post`),
KEY `id_tag` (`id_tag`)

--- TAGS Table ----
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

This is my very first post, so I'm sorry if I've missed something. Any help will be appreciated.

**** EDIT ****

Added real Tables and Queries. Note that **Posts is now named Noticias** and **Posts_tags is now named Tags_Noticias** . Added MySQL Explain from PHPMyAdmin and JetProfiler.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `noticias` (
`id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`volanta` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`titulo` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`texto` text NOT NULL,
`fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
`fecha_modificado` datetime NOT NULL,
`id_autor` int(2) NOT NULL,
`id_seccion` int(2) NOT NULL,
`id_posicion` int(1) NOT NULL,
`publicado` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`clave_primaria` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`url` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`meta_titulo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`meta_descripcion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`redirect` int(1) NOT NULL,
`estado_seo` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'danger',
`geo_data` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`media_principal` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_autor` (`id_autor`),
KEY `id_seccion` (`id_seccion`),
KEY `id_posicion` (`id_posicion`),
KEY `fecha` (`fecha`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=98560;
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`descripcion` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `descripcion` (`descripcion`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=21097 ;
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags_noticias` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_tag` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_noticia` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_noticia` (`id_noticia`),
KEY `id_tag` (`id_tag`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=284979 ;
```

-

```
SELECT
  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS null as rows,
  noticias.id,
  noticias.titulo,
  noticias.fecha,
  noticias.url,
  noticias.publicado,
  noticias.estado_seo,
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.descripcion SEPARATOR ", ") as ntags
FROM noticias
JOIN tags_noticias ON tags_noticias.id_noticia = noticias.id
JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_noticias.id_tag
GROUP BY noticias.id
ORDER BY noticias.id DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```

[MySQL explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qmu0.png)
[JetProfiler Explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrbZg.png)

Comment: Do you have any indices on the columns involved in the join?

Comment: We would probably need to see the rest of the more complex query. Unless I'm missing something, I don't see any red flags here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Key definitions are at bottom post. Both posts and tags tables have ids as Primary keys and posts_tags has id as Primary key and id_post, id_tag as Index

Comment: @LukeGeneva Since the missing part of query are conditionals for filtering purposes I think there is no need to add them. Anyway, using this simple query the MySQL explain throws the attached at bottom post. Added the almost real table structures just in case.

Comment: a) Your query will not return posts that have no tags. Is that what you really want? b) If not, use left join and remove `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` (this will speed up your query to about 1/1000 time). c) Add an index `tags_noticias(id_noticia, id_tag)` (or remove the id from your table).

Comment: @Solarflare All posts must have at least 1 tag, so using INNER or LEFT JOIN won't be the difference I think. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
**Removing SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS did the trick**, but I'm interested in getting total rows for pagination purposes. Maybe running this query twice will be faster than using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ? Note that rows can be filtered so the COUNT must be performed before LIMIT clausule.

Comment: That's why I asked if you have posts without tags: You can just use a second query and write `select count(*) from noticias where ...` without the joins, since that number will be the same. At least if you don't filter for tags. If you DO filter for tags too, well, that is another problem and not in your question, I don't see any `where` anywhere in your question. You could probably still do a second query for the count, but the most efficient way would depend on your `where` filters that you forgot to add, but my crystal ball is broken at the moment. Maybe try the proposed index or ...

Comment: ... just use an estimate for your pagination (I guess you want to show the number of total results/pages? Estimates are a legit optimization, e.g, google will not give you the exact number of results either). Pagination will still work if you don't know the number of total rows (you can use numbers for `limit` that are higher than the number of rows if that is your concern). But how you would do that depends on your actual problem - you never mentioned that anywhere, so I can only guess right now how to optimize code to solve unknown requirements.